# I can't upgrade from 18.04 lts to 19.04

Tags: 18.04

I have recently installed ubuntu 18.04.2 lts on my computer but I cannot update to 19.04 no matter what what should I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the output of `cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`?

Comment: Before other considerations, you don't have to until 2023, the 18.04 release is a LTS, 5 years of support; 19.04 is an interim release supported with only 9 months. And you can't upgrade directly anyway. You´ d have to go 18.04 > 18.10 > 19.04. And if you *recently  installed* **why didn't you install 19.04 in the beginning?** If that was the end goal but again, not a good idea.

Comment: As already explained you can skip to next LTS (20.04) or go through all releases meaning you can't go from 18.04 to 19.04 *directly*.  You can re-install 19.04 using 'something else' & not format your partition; which will cause your programs to be noted, system directories to be wiped; install occurs then additional programs you added re-installed (if from Ubuntu repos) achieving the 'upgrade' thru re-install - but only LTS to LTS, or every-release upgrade is tested & supported.